# How to group multiple columns in one column using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, grouping

There are different type of data in case type 3 column like Out of box failure, damage, misdirected, rejected case, Not Applicable, Info Request, Please Specify. I want to group the data to two columns. One is Out of Box and another one is combination of other data.

So far, when I execute the script, for each data, it is creating a column. Therefore, there are so many columns. But I want just two columns. Below is the chart for the current result. 
[image]

```
function createGraph() {
      var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('');
      var sheet = data.getSheets()[0];

      //create chart 
      //if chart created, this will update the existing chart
      if (sheet.getCharts().length > 0){
      var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
      chart = chart.modify()
      .removeRange(chart.getRanges()[0])
     //.addRange(sheet.getRange("Y1:Y501"))
      .addRange(sheet.getRange("P1:P42"))
      .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
      .setOption('treatLabelsAsText', true)
      .setOption('applyAggregateData',0)
      .setNumHeaders(1)
      .setPosition(5, 6, 5, 5)
      .setOption("title", "Chart")
      .build()
      sheet.updateChart(chart)

    }
    else{

      //create new chart
    var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
    //.addRange(sheet.getRange("Y1:Y501"))
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("P1:P42"))
    .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
    .setOption('applyAggregateData',0)
    .setOption('treatLabelsAsText', true)
    .setNumHeaders(1)
    .setPosition(5, 6, 5, 5)
    .setOption("title", "Chart")
    .build()
    sheet.insertChart(chart)

    }
  }
```

I expect the output to show two columns. One is for Out of Box and another column is for the other data which is combination of damage, misdirected, rejected case, Not Applicable, Info Request, Please Specify.

Comment: Could you please share your spreadsheet to understand how your data is set up? However, having the `useFirstColumnAsDomain` option set to true will cause the members of column A to be the labels of the data.

Comment: Hi this is the link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZrMtrC6bPB7lbIjDSZkCvKvRYYhbVfCkFY5AKKTqbUc/edit?usp=sharing I have attached the chart I wanted in sheet 2. Please advice me how to create that type of chart.

Comment: Hi @Sriram I was unable to find an option to create the chart how you want it through the `EmbeddedChartBuilder`. I did find some [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) and an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) on how to create tables with multiple parts. Another recommendation I have is to mark the out-of-box entries in a different column, then you can add them to the chart separately.